# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(500))

Tags: mysql

I have converted my database from MSQL to MySQL and I'm getting the following error.

**Error Messages: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(500)) = 'Male' AND Responses.res_void = 0' at line 22**

I cannot work out the issue it looks valid to me? Is there a MySQL no no here?

```
SELECT
    Responses.res_col AS answer
    ,Responses.res_created AS dateCreated
    ,Responses.res_notes AS note
    ,Responses.question_id AS questionID
    ,Responses.res_id AS responseID
    ,Responses.student_id AS studentID
    ,Responses.res_answer AS subQuestion
    ,Responses.survey_id AS surveyID
    ,Responses.res_void AS void
    ,Student.res_answer AS filter
    FROM
        Responses, Responses AS Student
    WHERE
        Responses.student_id = Student.student_id
    AND
        Responses.survey_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.surveyID#"> 
    AND
        Student.survey_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.surveyID#"> 
    AND
        Responses.question_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.questionID#">                    AND
        CAST(Student.res_answer AS VARCHAR(500)) = '#arguments.filter#'
    AND Responses.res_void = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#arguments.void#">
```

Comment: @ta.speot.is where? This code runs on MSSQL.

Comment: Yet you tagged it as MySQL. Which one is it?

Comment: @Bojangles Read the *very first line* of the OP: *I have converted my database from MSQL to MySQL and I'm getting the following error.*, so he's converting his queries from MSSQL to MySQL.

Comment: I'm going to go away. And I'm going to learn to read. Then, I'm going to come back and make sensible comments worthy of someone with 20k+ rep `;)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not cast to the `VARCHAR()` type. The only text type you may cast to is `CHAR(n)`:

```
CAST(Student.res_answer AS CHAR(500)) = '#arguments.filter#'
```

From the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), the type for the result can be one of the following values:

- `BINARY[(N)]`
- `CHAR[(N)]`
- `DATE`
- `DATETIME`
- `DECIMAL[(M[,D])]`
- `SIGNED [INTEGER]`
- `TIME`
- `UNSIGNED [INTEGER]`